# Read parent locals in pug includes

Tags: pug

I am trying to read pug local vars from parent `.pug` file but it doesn't show the value

```
//- index.pug
- var title = "This is title";
- var pagename = "This is pagename";

p #{title}
include includes/content.pug
```

```
//- includes/content.pug
p #{pagename}
```

The expected result is:

```
<p>This is title</p>
<p>This is pagename</p>
```

But it showed nothing on second variables:

```
<p>This is title</p>
<p></p>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I reproduced your example and it works as expected - the parent variable is accessible from the child template.

Comment: @marzelin, It turned out it works using gulp build tools. Previously I'm using webpack and I think this is other bug on webpack.